# Karate - Polyglot Exception using js callSingle()

Tags: karate

In the code presented below, I am trying to interact with a database through the use of a js function within the karate framework. The query used to get some data works as expected, likewise auxiliary information is accessible. The same function within the js file can be ran through groovy just fine but seems to explode when ran within karate.

JS Function to be ran in karate through a callSingle():

```
function() { let dbUser = Java.type('dev.dao.dbUser') return dbUser.getId(karate.properties['username'])
```

dbUser:

```
class dbUser {
               static Integer getId(String email) {
                         db.sql.firstRow("select user_id from table.db_user where email = ?", [email]).userId
                                                  }
             }
```

Karate-config.js

```
    function fn() {
  let config = {
    project: karate.properties['vs.project'],
    environment: karate.properties['vs.environment'],
    baseUrl: karate.properties['vs.baseUrl'],
    timeZoneId: karate.properties['vs.timeZoneId'],
    env: karate.properties['vs.env'],
    proxy: {
     ...
      ]
      },
    demoUserId: 1,
    userId: karate.callSingle('classpath:proj/dev/js/dao/getDbUserId.js'),
    createDBuid: karate.read('classpath:proj/dev/js/createDBuid.js'),
    DBuid: karate.callonce('classpath:proj/dev/js/createDBuid.js')
  }
}
```

Error returned calling the getDbUserId.js:
[PolyglotError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBK2g.png)

<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException

- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge.callSingle(ScenarioBridge.java:243)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge.callSingle(ScenarioBridge.java:187)
- .fn(Unnamed:18)

Comment: Can you please try 1.3.0.RC1 and open an issue if you still see problems: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/1.3.0-Upgrade-Guide

Comment: Please post the error as text, an image.

Comment: I tried making my karate version 1.3.0.RC1, still seeing the polyglot issue appear. Will be opening an issue.